# how to display single value use arrayshit or other thing (without loop) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I use display value or data. In case of a single value use loop, but I know this is a bad habit. How can I solve this? for example I use this:

```
@foreach($result as $result)
{{$result->data}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm confused. what's this : `$result as $result` ? and can see how you pass data ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Did you mean "arrayshift"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code doesn't tell anything, and also you have this code all wrong.

You can't name a pointer as the same name of the array, ($result as $result ???) you will have wrong results or errors.

Also inside the froeach you are referencing a variable that doesn't exists (?).

In my opinion "foreach" is necessary to loop through arrays.

I really don't know what are you trying to do, so that would be great if you expand your question and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that with some code like this:

`@if($result)
{{$data}}
@endif`

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below see

```html
//example in file ExampleController.php
use App\Posts;
public function showAll(){
  $data = Posts::all();
 return view('showall',['result'=>$data]);
}


//file web.php

Route::get('/show-all','ExampleController@showAll');

//show-all.blade.php

@foreach($result as $value)
  {{$value.title_name}}
@endforeah
```